# How to correctly quote `adb shell su -c`

Tags: adb, shell

`adb shell su -c` is a commonly used adb command. Normally you just need to append arguments to the command line like this:

```
adb shell su -c echo ab
```

However, things can be tricky if you want to add quotes. For example, to print `a  b` (there are 2 spaces), these won't work:

```
adb shell su -c echo "a  b"
adb shell su -c "echo \"a  b\""
adb shell su -c "echo 'a  b'"
```

You have to use these:

```
adb shell su -c "\"echo \\\"a  b\\\"\""
adb shell "su -c \"echo \\\"a  b\\\"\""
adb shell su -c "\"echo 'a  b'\""
adb shell "su -c \"echo 'a  b'\""
```

I'd like to know which is the standard way of writing such a command. Standard means it handles quotes correctly and in the most straightforward way.

My current research:

- `adb` handles command arguments the same way as `ssh`: Arguments are connected (with space) into a string, and that string is executed.
- `su -c` expects a single string as the command line, and it doesn't do the concatenation for you.

So I think the most standard way of writing `adb shell su -c` should be like:

```
adb shell "su -c \"echo \\\"a  b\\\"\""
```

However, I'm not very confident about this. Does anyone have concrete reference confirming what I'm doing or showing I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: When I get in this kind of situation I do: `adb shell 'su -c "echo a\ \ b"'`. I use single quotes to enclose everything after `adb shell` and double quotes inside, wherever needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to use single-quotes (`'`) around the subcommand:

```
adb shell 'su -c echo "a  b"'
```

But please note that usually within single-quotes everything is taken literally and variables are not expanded. This doesn't apply when you nest quotes like this. As an example:

```
myvar='123'
echo "$myvar"   # prints 123
echo '$myvar'   # prints $myvar
```

But: (assuming `$myvar` is set to `'123'` **within the adb shell (e.g. on phone)**)

```
adb shell 'su -c echo "$myvar"'    # prints 123
```

In case you want to use your own shell variables to be included within the `adb` subcommand, you can simply flip around the quotes:

```
myvar='test'
adb shell "su -c echo '$myvar'"    # prints test
```